# Understanding Lorentz transformation

Tags: special-relativity

The time part of Lorentz transformation is given by,

$$t'=\gamma\left(t-\frac{vx}{c^2}\right)$$

I am having trouble in understanding this formula.

Suppose that $t=t'=0$ the formula above tell us that $x=0$. This means  that for example if observer $O$ and $O'$ are separated by a distance $d$ they cannot set both of their clock to zero. Why is that so?

Answer (score 2):

Note that the transformations:

\begin{aligned}x' &= \gamma \left(x- v t\right)\\ t' &= \gamma\left(t - \frac{vx}{c^2}\right)\end{aligned}

have been **defined** so that when $t=t'=0$, $x=x'=0$, meaning that the clocks are *already* synchronised. This is the usual convention: the two observers in $S$ and $S'$ synchronise their clocks when their "origins" coincide. This ist, of course, not essential, but it certainly makes the equations a little more compact. I believe it's usually discussed in most introductory derivations of the Lorentz Transformations.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Here is an image of the $(t,x)$ and $(t',x')$ axes.

Note that $t = 0$ is the $x$-axis, and $t' = 0$ is the $x'$-axis. Based on the picture, you can see that the $x$-axis and $x'$-axis only intersect at $x = x' = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Lorentz transformation are contained in the Poincare transformation where the time coordinate transform as  $$t'=\gamma\left(t-\frac{vx}{c^2}\right)+a$$ where $a$ is some constant. So for example if they are separated by a distance $d$ if we set $a=\gamma\frac{vd}{c^2}$ we see that both of their clock are zero.